# Qt: Show popup menu, close if I click anywhere outside of it

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to show a menu in Qt with the following functionality: clicking anywhere outside of the menu will close it, but the click will be processed by the receiving widget. As far as I know, this rules out using `setWindowFlag(Qt::Popup)` because the click that closed the popup will be 'eaten' and not processed any further. I'd love to know if there is a way around this.

For the time being, I'm overriding `focusOutEvent` like so:

```
class Menu : public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Menu(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent){
        setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        resize(200, 100);
    }

public slots:

    void showMenu(QPoint point)
    {
        move(point);
        show();
        setFocus(); // so that focusOutEvent will be trigerred
    }

protected:

    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event) override
    {
        hide();
    }
};
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
class Window : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Window(): m_menu()
    {
        auto* list = new QListWidget();
        list->addItems(QStringList() << "item1" << "item2" << "item3");

        connect(list, &QListWidget::itemClicked, [this](){
            m_menu.showMenu(QCursor::pos());
        });

        // Layout stuff
        auto central_widget = new QWidget();
        auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(central_widget);
        layout->addWidget(list);
        layout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(20,200, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
        setCentralWidget(central_widget);
    }


public:

    ~Window(){}

private:

    Menu m_menu;
};
```

Single clicking on any of the items in the list will show the menu and clicking anywhere on the grey background will close the menu.

[image: showMenu]

The issue I'm facing is that when the menu is shown, focus is lost from the main window (photo on the right, the titlebar buttons and selected item are greyed out). Focus is lost because of calling `setFocus` on the menu but if I don't use it then the `QFocusOutEvent`s are not trigerred and the menu doesn't close.

The same happens if I use `setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating)` on the menu.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to use Qt::Popup without the 'eaten' clicks issue?
2. If not, is there a way to show the menu without losing the focus from the main window but still trigger the `focusOutEvent`s as necessary?

Using Qt 5.15.1 on MacOS 11.2.3. Thanks for reading through my long post!

Comment: One way I have done it in the past is to make a fullscreen transparent item over top of the main window, and then draw the popup on top of that. If the transparent item sees a click, then close the popup.

Comment: Please do not use focus for this. Some window managers (like mine) change the focus when moving the mouse instead of clicking which will break your design. You can try catching mouse events in the main window and close the dialog from there if you don't care about clicks outside your application.

Comment: If you keep focus on main window user wont be able select menu item using keyboard, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JarMan This is interesting. I'm trying to implement this so that the events are propagated to the underlying widget but for some reason I can't forward the event successfully. Would you mind having a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945267/qt-propagate-mouse-clicks-through-a-transparent-widget