# How to propagate mouse clicks through a transparent widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, mouseevent

I'm trying to create a widget which, when shown, it will intercept any mouse clicks, process them, but then forward the click to the widget that was under the mouse when it was clicked.

I've created a class that represents this widget; all it does for now is capture mouse release events, hide itself, and post the event to the widget the click was intended for using `QApplication::postEvent`:

```cpp
class Overlay : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    Overlay(QWidget* parent)
        : QWidget(parent){}

protected:

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        hide();
        auto child = parentWidget()->childAt(event->pos()); // get the child widget the event was intended for
        auto e = new QMouseEvent(*event);
        if(child) QCoreApplication::postEvent(child, e); // why doesn't this have any effect?
        event->accept();
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
    {
        QPainter p(this);
        p.fillRect(rect(), QColor(0,0,0,150));
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, the call to `postEvent` doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Here is an example where I'm setting up some child widgets; clicking on any widget will print something out:

```cpp
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    {
        m_overlay = new Overlay(this);
        m_overlay->hide();

        auto button = new QPushButton("Add overlay");
        auto button2 = new QPushButton("PushButton");
        auto list = new QListWidget();
        list->addItems(QStringList() << "item1" << "item2" << "item3");

        connect(list, &QListWidget::itemClicked, [](const QListWidgetItem* item)
        {
           qDebug() << item->text();
        });

        connect(button2, &QPushButton::clicked, []()
        {
            qDebug() << "Button clicked";
        });

        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]()
        {
            m_overlay->setGeometry(rect());
            m_overlay->raise();
            m_overlay->show();
        });

        auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(list);
        layout->addWidget(button);
        layout->addWidget(button2);
    }

public:

    ~Widget(){}

private:

    Overlay* m_overlay;
};
```

I've confirmed that clicks on the overlay are captured, and the overlay is hidden as intended, but the event is not propagated to the underlying widget. Using `QApplication::sendEvent` doesn't work either. What am I missing?

Using Qt 5.15.1 on macOS 11.2.3.

Comment: I'm not sure but I suspect the event you're posting will be deleted as soon as the code returns to the Qt framework.  That is, is will be deleted *before* the new target object ever sees it.  Try using [`QCoreApplication::sendEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent) instead to see if that has any effect -- although even if it works it's probably not the correct solution.

Comment: @ G.M. Unfortunately, sendEvent doesn't make a difference

Comment: I think the problems is `hide()`, a hidden widget won't receive any events AFAIK. What you need is a fully transparent widget, not a hidden widget. I don't have time for a full answer, but I did similar things and it should be possible.

Comment: @ user1095108: Thank you, but I'm not trying to forward the event to the hidden widget. Instead, the hidden widget posts an event to a child widget that is visible.

Comment: Sure, but the overlay won't receive the event, if it is hidden. There's nothing to forward.